# How I can implement Typescript into ASP.NET MVC 3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, typescript, project

I have ASP.NET MVC 3 project with Razor syntax. Now I implement js code inline html markup. It's temporaly case. Now I would like use TypeScript in my project.

Could you please how I should add typescript into my project instead of inline js code?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please how I should add typescript into my project instead of inline js code

Instead of inline js use a `script` tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

and compile your TypeScript to JavaScript. More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWXGMug_Rmo&hd=1